# Using ggplot in R, Iwould like to combine individual bar chart graphs into one large graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that looks like this

**Field**  **Gender**  **%**
A            M          .56
A            F          .75
B            M          .66
B            F          .56
C            M          .77
C            F          .88

When I use facet_wrap to graph this, I get individual graphs for each 'Field'. Each graph has the 'Gender' field on the x-axis and the '%' on the Y axis. However, I would like to have a single large graph that has both 'Field' and 'Gender' on the x-axis.

Thanks,
Sultana

Comment: Sorry, the data I typed in did not come out right. The 'Field' variable has the values 'A', 'B', 'C'. The 'Gender' variable has the values 'M', 'F' . I obtained the percentage values by grouping the data by 'Field' and 'Gender' and manipulating counts.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
data.frame(f = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
           g = c("M","F","M","F","M","F"),
           p = c(0.45, 0.75, 0.66, 0.56, 0.77, 0.88)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = f,
                y = p,
                fill = g))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge")
```

Comment: Thanks. That sort of works, but I have the problem of spacing and labels. All the bars are equidistant. I need the M,F bars within each field to be close together and greater distance between the fields. does that make sense. Also, all the labels are bunched together